# Connect with Facebook button, Gowalla's style

Tags: facebook, button

I am searching for over an hour for a Connect with Facebook button that is similar to the one Gowalla is using ([link](http://gowalla.com/users/new))

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Javascript SDK this question should help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792231/fblogin-button-custom

This code generates a similar one to Gowalla.

```
<fb:login-button size="xlarge"
                 onlogin="Log.info('onlogin callback')">
  Connect with Facebook
</fb:login-button>
```

This page lets you try out various things: http://fbrell.com/xfbml/fb:login-button

Comment: Actually, I was looking only for that image, sorry I didn't make it clear. But thanks for your answer!

Comment: If you right click on the image on their site you should be able to find out where it lives and then take a copy.

Comment: It resides on their server, so is it legal to copy it and use it for my own needs? I thought the image would be somewhere public, licensed as free.

Comment: As you could generate it yourself using the method above, I would have thought not. You could go to the page which lets you try out things and generate one there, and then copy it.

Comment: I missed you. Where should I go and copy the picture?

Comment: http://fbrell.com/xfbml/fb:login-button

Comment: But those are still Facebook-like images. I need that kind of image which Gowalla has (and also Foursquare).